# TypeScript: multiple destructuring and type assertion

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm wondering how you can assert the type of multiple variables when using destructuring in TypeScript.

Consider:

`const { OneTypeOfObject, AndAnother } = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto').build('iAmANameSpace');`

How can I assert that `OneTypeOfObject` has a type of `OneType` and `AndAnother` has a type of `OtherType`?

I can make them **all** `any` like this:

`const { OneTypeOfObject, AndAnother } = <any>ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto').build('iAmANameSpace');`

What I'd actually like to do is something like this:

`const { <OneType>OneTypeOfObject, <OtherType>AndAnother } = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto').build('iAmANameSpace');`

There's clearly been thought about this sort of thing:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/7a74d9f8d021f50201765d2170af8d249af90320

But I can't find the answer based on what I've seen....

#### Update

I tried both of David's approaches but neither worked.  This is the code used for approach 2:

```
interface OneType extends ProtoBuf.ProtoBuf {
  new(): any;
}

interface OtherType extends ProtoBuf.ProtoBuf {
  new(): any;
}

const { <OneType>OneTypeOfObject, <OtherType>AndAnother } = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto').build('iAmANameSpace');
```

It caused this error:

> Type 'ProtoBuf' is not assignable to type '{ OneTypeOfObject: OneType; AndAnother: OtherType; }'. Property 'OneTypeOfObject' is missing in type 'ProtoBuf'.

Answer (score 1):

Desturcturing with types was confusing to me at first as well. There are there ways you could accomplish this.

The easiest have `ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto')` return the appropriate type (which I realize isn't always possible or easy).

OR

`const { OneTypeOfObject, AndAnother } = <{ OneTypeOfObject: TypeA; AndAnother : TypeB }> ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto');`

OR

`const { OneTypeOfObject, AndAnother } : { OneTypeOfObject: TypeA; AndAnother : TypeB }  = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto');`

Comment: Actually that didn't work David - I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: It's hard to say with the example as it exists.  Does `ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./ohYesProtobufs.proto').build('iAmANameSpace')` return an object both the values you're looking for?

Comment: It does - but that's not part of the protobufjs definition.